# How can I solve it if ioctl always returns "device or resource is busy"?

Tags: c++, linux, camera, ioctl

I try to send/receive data to/from camera registers in Ubuntu 20.04, and want to use ioctl to control what I mentioned.

I get usb device path and port number as below,

```
laptop05:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID a168:0970 My Camera
```

In my program, open usb device handle as below,

```
deviceHandle = ::open("/dev/bus/usb/001/006", (O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK));
```

and close usb device handle as below when I close my program,

```
if(deviceHandle > (-1))
    ::close(deviceHandle);
```

the code what I sent to my camera is following,

```
struct usbdevfs_ctrltransfer ctrl;
const int tm = 20;
const int tm_out = 1000; //0;
const int buf_len = 2;
unsigned char tx_buf[buf_len] = { 0, 0 };

tx_buf[0] = 0xF2;
tx_buf[1] = 0x01;
ctrl.bRequestType = USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE | USB_DIR_OUT // 0x21;
ctrl.bRequest = 0x01;
ctrl.wValue = 0x200;
ctrl.wIndex = 0x400;
ctrl.wLength = buf_len;
ctrl.timeout = tm_out;
ctrl.data = (void*)tx_buf;

int ans = ioctl(deviceHandle, USBDEVFS_CONTROL, &ctrl);
QThread::msleep(tm);

if(ans < 0)
{
    qDebug() << "sending 0xF201 is failed.";
    qDebug() << "ioctl failed and returned errno = " << strerror(errno);
}
```

After sending data to my camera, ioctl always returns "device or resource is busy".

May I know how I can solve this issue, so I can send data to my camera successfully?

Thanks for help.

// ****** my terminal-only program is below, thanks for help.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>

// https://codebrowser.dev/linux/linux/include/uapi/linux/usb/ch9.h.html
/*
 * USB directions
 *
 * This bit flag is used in endpoint descriptors' bEndpointAddress field.
 * It's also one of three fields in control requests bRequestType.
 */
#define USB_DIR_OUT 0   /* to device */
#define USB_DIR_IN  0x80    /* to host */

/*
 * USB types, the second of three bRequestType fields
 */
#define USB_TYPE_MASK       (0x03 << 5)
#define USB_TYPE_STANDARD   (0x00 << 5)
#define USB_TYPE_CLASS      (0x01 << 5)
#define USB_TYPE_VENDOR     (0x02 << 5)
#define USB_TYPE_RESERVED   (0x03 << 5)

/*
 * USB recipients, the third of three bRequestType fields
 */
#define USB_RECIP_MASK      0x1f
#define USB_RECIP_DEVICE    0x00
#define USB_RECIP_INTERFACE 0x01
#define USB_RECIP_ENDPOINT  0x02
#define USB_RECIP_OTHER     0x03
/* From Wireless USB 1.0 */
#define USB_RECIP_PORT      0x04
#define USB_RECIP_RPIPE         0x05

void turnOnLight(const int deviceHandle)
{
    if(deviceHandle < 0)
        return;

    struct usbdevfs_ctrltransfer ctrl;
    const int tm_out = 1000; //0;
    const int buf_len = 2;
    unsigned char tx_buf[buf_len] = { 0, 0 };

    //case eAllLeds: // F201, F300.
    tx_buf[0] = 0xF2;
    tx_buf[1] = 0x01;
    
    ctrl.bRequestType = USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE | USB_DIR_OUT; // 0x21;
    ctrl.bRequest = 0x01;
    ctrl.wValue = 0x200;
    ctrl.wIndex = 0x400;
    ctrl.wLength = buf_len;
    ctrl.timeout = tm_out;
    ctrl.data = (void*)tx_buf;

    int ans = ::ioctl(deviceHandle, USBDEVFS_CONTROL, &ctrl);
    //int errorNo = errno;

    if(ans < 0)
        perror("sending 0xF201 is failed, perror output:");

    tx_buf[0] = 0xF3;
    tx_buf[1] = 0x00;
     
    ctrl.bRequestType = USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE | USB_DIR_OUT; //0x21;
    ctrl.bRequest = 0x01;
    ctrl.wValue = 0x200;
    ctrl.wIndex = 0x400;
    ctrl.wLength = buf_len;
    ctrl.timeout = tm_out;
    ctrl.data = (void*)tx_buf;

    ans = ::ioctl(deviceHandle, USBDEVFS_CONTROL, &ctrl);
    //errorNo = errno;

    if(ans < 0)
        perror("sending 0xF300 is failed, perror output:");
}

void turnOffLight(const int deviceHandle)
{
    if(deviceHandle < 0)
        return;

    struct usbdevfs_ctrltransfer ctrl;
    const int tm_out = 1000; //0;
    const int buf_len = 2;
    unsigned char tx_buf[buf_len] = { 0, 0 };

    //case eLedOff: // F200, F300.
    tx_buf[0] = 0xF2;
    tx_buf[1] = 0x00;
    
    ctrl.bRequestType = USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE | USB_DIR_OUT; //0x21;
    ctrl.bRequest = 0x01;
    ctrl.wValue = 0x200;
    ctrl.wIndex = 0x400;
    ctrl.wLength = buf_len;
    ctrl.timeout = tm_out;
    ctrl.data = (void*)tx_buf;

    int ans = ::ioctl(deviceHandle, USBDEVFS_CONTROL, &ctrl);
    //int errorNo = errno;

    if(ans < 0)
        perror("sending 0xF200 is failed, perror output:");
 
    tx_buf[0] = 0xF3;
    tx_buf[1] = 0x00;
    
    ctrl.bRequestType = USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE | USB_DIR_OUT; //0x21;
    ctrl.bRequest = 0x01;
    ctrl.wValue = 0x200;
    ctrl.wIndex = 0x400;
    ctrl.wLength = buf_len;
    ctrl.timeout = tm_out;
    ctrl.data = (void*)tx_buf;

    ans = ::ioctl(deviceHandle, USBDEVFS_CONTROL, &ctrl);
    //errorNo = errno;

    if(ans < 0)
        perror("sending 0xF300 is failed, perror output:");
}

int main(void)
{
    int deviceHandle = ::open("/dev/bus/usb/001/006", (O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK));

    if(deviceHandle < 0)
    {
        printf("Opening device is failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }

#if 1
    turnOnLight(deviceHandle);
#else
    turnOffLight(deviceHandle);
#endif

    if(deviceHandle > (-1))
        ::close(deviceHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must check `errno` ***directly*** after the system call you want to test. And *only* if it actually failed. You call `QThread::sleep` *and* use `qDebug` in between, both of which might alter the value of `errno`. Unless the system call documentation specifies otherwise (and [`ioctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) does not) then the value of `errno` is *indeterminate* unless the the function actually failed. And in C++ using indeterminate values of any kind, in any way, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The good news is that you can *save* the value of `errno` into your own variable, if you really need to possibly do other calls between the failed function and the reporting of the error.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, thanks for your reply. I follow your suggestion, and comment QThread::sleep out, and save value of errno after calling ioctl(). I still get "device or resource is busy" when running my test program. May I know what I can do next step, so I can send data to my camera successful? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume that no other program is using the camera? It still doesn't work right after reboot? Do your program perhaps by mistake open the device multiple times? And does the camera and its driver support this "command" that you try to send? Is the command in the right byte-order? Is the `usbdevfs_ctrltransfer` structure initialized as specified by the documentation? Do you remember to check for failures from `open` before you call `ioctl`?

Comment: If possible, please try to create a [mre] to show us. You don't really need any Qt stuff in the example, a bare-bones classical terminal-only program should be enough to replicate the problem. And if it doesn't, then the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, terminal-only program is a good idea, I will try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I try my terminal-only program, but I still get "device or resource is busy". My terminal-only program has been attached. Any help will be appreciated.